# socket programing cant connect to another network

Tags: python, sockets, ip-address, portforwarding

I recently wrote a client/server pair in python using sockets,but the problem is client doesn't connect to server on another network.I've tried port forwarding and making internal IP address static, a question which really bother's me is do i need External/Public IP address to make the client connect and if this is the case what to do when the ISP changes my External IP address. Please give some suggestions,thanks.

```
code:

PORT=8888
srvsock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
srvsock.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
srvsock.bind( ('', PORT) )
srvsock.listen( 10 )
print 'server now listening on PORT '+str(PORT)

while 1:

  clisock, (remhost, remport) = srvsock.accept()
  dl_information_file="server.txt"
  if os.path.exists(dl_information_file):
      f=open('server.txt','rb')
      read=f.read()
      clisock.send( read )
      f.close()
```

Comment: You don't need public IP addresses to communicate with sockets, but you must post your code (or the relevant parts), otherwise no one would be able to help you.

Comment: The basic network setup would also help. 1. In which network is the server located IP address, subnetmask, etc. same for the network in
which the client is located. Is other communication between this networks possible, how they are connected ...?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to run both server and client from the same computer (connect to localhost)

If that works your problem is port forwarding related. 
see: [how to portforward](http://portforward.com)

Comment: it runs on the same computer and same network but fails over internet.

Answer (score 0):

Are the client and server on a local network or is the client and server separated by the Internet?

If the server is running on a machine behind a NAT, you will have to do portforwarding on that and make sure that the machine's IP is static or that you update the client with the updated IP.

If the server is within your own network, you can use `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())` to get the IP of your interface (careful, you may have more than one) and use that IP to bind a socket.

You may also use WireShark to troubleshoot the connection - you can see what packets are making their way out of your client and what packets are making their way to your server.

Without further code and more information on the network, it's really hard to say any more - it could be the firewall, it could be the NAT, it could be a badly configured interface.

**edit:** It appears that you're binding the socket to `''`, which means it should be bound to the localhost port, meaning that the server listens for connections on the local loopback (127.0.0.1). This interface is not accessible to any other machine that the one which the server is running on.
You should use either a statically configured IP in a variable in your script, or that `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()))`.

Comment: how to implement socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())), thanks

Comment: This is an example:
`srvsock.bind ((socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()), PORT))`. Just remember, this method resolves the IP of a hostname provided by getfqdn(), which in turn gets the hostname of the first interface, which may not be the right interface you're looking for - this can happen if you have hamachi or virtualbox for example.
Another solution is to checkout the IP of the server and feed it manually to the bind function in the script.

Comment: can i bind it to static ip address

Comment: I assume the server is behind a NAT. If so then yes, you can check out the IP of the server on the local network, bind the server to that IP and then set up port forwarding on your router. I believe this should work.

Comment: `''` means INADDR_ANY. It doesn't mean localhost. Binding to hostname that resolves to private address doesn't solve the OP's problem (communicate over internet).

Comment: Thanks for the `''` information. If the OP binded it to a private address and then forwarded that port on the router, wouldn't that take care of the NAT?